# Jasmine / Backbone

Tags: backbone.js, jasmine

My Jasmine tests used to pass.  However, I implemented a Base Backbone view that provides functionality for a few common views.  After this, I cannot get the simple test below to pass.  It seems the DOM element (div) does not exist, thus my show view is not rendering properly. Any thoughts or recommendations on why this is occurring and ways to solve it?

Two Backbone Views, one extends off of the other:

```
var stockShowView = Base.extend({
  tagName: 'div',
  className: 'showSecurity',
  template: _.template(showTpl),
  ....
  render: function() {
    this.$el.html(this.template({
      stock: this.model.toJSON()
    }));
  }
  ....return stockShowView;

var Base = Backbone.View.extend({
  initialize: function() {....//no render function
```

Jasmine Test

```
  stock_showView = new stockShowView({model: model});
  stock_showView.render();

  expect(stock_showView.tagName).toEqual('div');
```

Error

```
 Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
```

Router

```
  router.on('route:showPost', function(id) {
    if (globals.stocks) {
      var stockpost = new StockModel({_id: id});
        stockpost.fetch({
          reset: true,
          success: function(stockpost) {
            var stock_showView = new stockShowView({model: stockpost});
            $("#view_box").html(stock_showView.render().el);
          }
      });
```

Comment: without the complete code its impossible to tell. share more, ideally in a jsFiddle

Comment: Yeah you are right.  However, it is a lot of code.  I guess my main question was when calling .render() as above, is Jasmine dipping into the Base view for the render function rather than the stockShowView explicity?   Is it utilizing Backbone's router as I have an if statement (added to question)?  Or is it simply trying to render the stock_showView?

Answer (score 0):

You should write the tagName element with uppercase letters. Try this:

```
expect(stock_showView.el.nodeName).toEqual("DIV");
```

Comment: And also u can use this article http://tinnedfruit.com/2011/03/03/testing-backbone-apps-with-jasmine-sinon.html very good tutorial for starters